# Recording in Selenium IDE for Firefox has Element not found issue

Tags: selenium, firefox-addon-sdk, selenium-ide

There is an error for clicking the Add User button and filling out the form. This has happened on Mac and PC. The Mac gets to the user information form. The PC stops at the Add User.

```
Element link=Add User not found
Element //input[@id='firstName'] not found
```

I've been told it's because the the browser looses focus. I've researched this and can't find a IDE solution. I'm using the IDE to record all clicks and filling out the form. I'm not writing this script. Playback has the above error.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Also pasting relevant HTML would help, thank you!

Comment: It means that most probably your locator is not valid. if thats the case you will need to identify different locator. may be CSS locator.

Comment: People here can help you in making the valid locator if you can copy-paste html snippet of those fields/buttons.